# Querying data from DynamoDB using AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a react application and I am using AWS amplify.  My question is, when I query data from DynamoDB, is the proper way to go through AWS AppSync and then do I have a lambda function that queries the db or does appsync just do that?  What is the proper path to do this?  Is it React->Appsync->lambda->DynamoDb or am I missing something?  Also, does dynamo db need to sit inside of something like an EC2 instance or AWS fargate or can it just sit alone?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do React->AppSync->DynamoDb. AppSync has a first order integration available for DynamoDB meaning that DynamoDB can be an AppSync datasource. So you can query, update, delete items in DynamoDb directly from AppSync without having to go through Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You can first export GraphQl generated queries then next use this code(GraphQl generate folder like this **src/graphql/queries.js**

```
const client = require("../common/gqlClient")();
const gql = require("graphql-tag");
const _ = require("lodash");

const { clubBySportStatus } = require("../common/queriesAndMutations");

    let allClubsList = async (sport) => {
      try {
         let clubsList;
         let clubsInfoList = [];
        let nextTokenInfo = null;
        do{ 
        let clubs = await client.query({
          query: gql(clubBySportStatus),
          variables: {
            sport: sport,
            eq: { status: "ACTIVE" },
          },
          limit: 100,
          nextToken: nextTokenInfo,
          fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        });
        clubsList = clubs.data.clubBySportStatus.items;
         clubsList.forEach((item) => clubsInfoList.push(item));
          nextTokenInfo = clubs.data.clubBySportStatus.nextToken;
        } while (Boolean(nextTokenInfo));
        if (clubsInfoList && clubsInfoList.length) {
          return {
            success: true,
            data: clubsInfoList,
          };
        }
      } catch (eX) {
        console.error(`Error in allClubsList: ${JSON.stringify(eX)}`);
        return {
          success: false,
          message: eX.message,
        };
      }
    };
```